# FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql-13

0

I am getting the below errors every 2 or 3 days(when high usage of database) and also postmaster.pid file is changed automatically. my Database version is postgresql 13

Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Out of memory: Kill process 2591 (postgres)

LOG: terminating any other active server processes

FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

below are the my configuration parameters and my server capacity is 4cpu's and 16 GB RAM, please help me.

ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections = '400';

alter system set effective_io_concurrency=100

alter system set log_min_duration_statement=3000;

alter system set log_destination='stderr,csvlog'

alter system set effective_cache_size = '8GB';

alter system set max_connections = '400';

alter system set work_mem = '6MB'; - alter system set max_wal_size ='2GB';

alter system set max_worker_processes ='4';

alter system set max_parallel_workers ='4';

alter system set max_parallel_workers_per_gather ='4'; -

alter system set wal_keep_size ='500MB';

it is big issue for my application? and which parameter I need to change for overcome this issue.

Comment: You're out of memory, as the log says.  Is that an issue?  Yes.  What can you do about it?  No idea: that's a matter for system administration, it depends on the particular instance.  In any case this isn't really a programming question, so it's probably off topic here.

Comment: Also, what's up with the formatting?   Why does the first line read '0'?